# Can I derive a formula for this algebraic expansion?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, induction

I have this algebraic expression where $\mu$ is a constant, $I$ is identity matrix and $R_N,R_{N-1},...,R_1$ are a sequence of square matrices (so order of multiplication matters: $R_1R_2 \neq R_2R_1$).
$$E_N = \prod_{n=N}^{1}((-1)^n\mu I + R_n)$$
Using mathematical induction, the product can be expanded to the following sum:
$$E_N = \sum_{n=0}^{N}(\mu^n A_n)$$
where $A_n$ must be determined in terms of all $R_n$. Is it possible to derive a formula to generalize this expansion?

**Example:** for example for N=3, we have:
$$
A_0 = R_3R_2R_1 \\
A_1 = R_3R_1-R_2R_1-R_3R_2 \\
A_2 = -R_3+R_2-R_1 \\
A_3 = 1
$$

Comment: Looks uncannily like Newton's symmetric polynomials, with appropriate powers of $-1$ attached in front of them. I don't know if it helps, but maybe I will come back later and have a go at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is handy to define $S_{n} = (-1)^nR_n$, and rewrite your expression as
\begin{align*}
E_N 
&= 
\prod_{n=N}^{1} (\mu I + ((-1)^nR_n)
\\&=
\prod_{n=N}^{1}(-1)^n (\mu I + S_n)
\\&=
(-1)^{\binom{N+1}{2}} \prod_{n=N}^{1} (\mu I + S_n)
\\&=
(-1)^{\binom{N+1}{2}} \sum_{n=0}^{N} \mu^n B_n,
\end{align*}
where $B_{n}$ is the sum of all products of $N-n$ of the $S_{i}$ of the form
$$
S_{i_{1}} S_{i_{2}} \dots S_{i_{N-n}},
\quad
\text{for }i_{1} > i_{2} > \dots > i_{N-n}.$$

Comment: is it combination $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$?

Comment: I am using examples and seeing that "Bn is the sum of all products of N−n of the Si" is true. Can you explain what is the reason?

Comment: Simply because when expanding the product you have to choose for each factor $\mu I + S_{i}$ either $\mu$, or $S_{i}$. You can do it by induction on $N$, if you wish.